# PCB dual LED emitter, TIA and voltage regulator (beginner)

Tags: power-supply, led, pcb, circuit-design, photodiode

[image]Does this PCB look good for this operation?

The schematic is attached.

I have a voltage regulator connectected to an LED emitter. Voltage regulator to TIA . TIA then is attached to active high pass filter, then a peak detector which then outputs to another circuit to a comparator. LED will be attached with a wire soldered to JP1 and JP2 and a photodiode with a wire soldered to JP3 and JP4.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are those silkscreen labels? Electrical details aside, that's very messy.

Comment: I also see a few unrouted traces, so the PCB won't actually work unless you plan to add jumper wires. And then there's the obligatory "please don't use 741s", but that's a critique of the circuit, not the PCB.

Comment: Hi Hearth I have updated the traces so all are connected. Should it work now? Also, in the future what op amp do you recommend? What is the very best one similar to the 741?

Comment: There really isn't any "very best" op amp. It depends on what you need it to do and how much you're willing to pay. The 741 is just completely obsolete and a very poor op amp by most any measure.

Comment: I understand and thanks for the comment. How does the circuit look now? It all seems to make sense but I do apologize for the schematic symbols.

Comment: Well, you should add a ground pour, that's always a good idea. I would also point out that there's nothing wrong with routing signals _under_ devices, quite a few of your traces, especially on the bottom layer, could be much shorter than they are if you just route them underneath your 741s.

Comment: You should increase the minimum clearances.   You have tracks running unnecessarily close to pads (e.g Q1).  Check you pad size and pin spacing on C6 & C7.  You should upload your Gerbers to Advanced Circuits free DFM https://www.4pcb.com/free-pcb-file-check/index.html